# Cannot import dependecies in kotlin multiplatform mobile

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I created a new kotlin multiplatform mobile project. I followed official documentation.
Basic project is working, I was able to build it on android without problems.

I wanted to add some api and I found `ktor`, which I have never used before. I followed docs here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/use-ktor-for-networking.html and tutorial here: https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-multiplatform-very-beginners-guide-part-2-api-d54f7326dc57 and all changes I did are:

I added `ktor` libraries into `build.gradle.kts(:shared)`:

```
sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.5.0")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.5.0")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:1.5.0")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
```

And I created `Api` class where I wanted to create and use the `HttpClient`:

```
class Api() {
    private val client = HttpClient()

    suspend fun fetch(): String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

BUT `HttpCLient()` is "Unresolved reference" and it cannot be imported. I also tried to manually add import `io.ktor.client.HttpClient`

but `io` is "Unresolved reference".
Also I tried numerous rebuilds/cleans/syncs.
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: I face the same issue with 1.5.1, did you find out what the issue is?

Comment: Using version 1.4.2 seems to work, but I doubt that this is the actual solution?

Comment: I assume you speak about your IDE when you say "unresolved reference"? I just tried the same here with plugin `kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.4.21"` and `ktor:1.5.0` (also `1.5.1`, but only in `commonMain` and also just added code in `commonMain`) and it was able to resolve it... however I am using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2021.1 EAP... maybe something was fixed? ;-) I know I had such issues with Intellij before, not only with multiplatform, but I forgot how I solved it :-) and now it works :-P

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  Did you find the solution?

Comment: I faced the same issue. Updating to 1.5.4 or 1.6.0 didn't help.
When I commented out everything inside 'iosTarget("ios")' the import statements became good again.
I suspect the issue lies elsewhere even though Android Studio isn't telling you where.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on windows 7 with Android Studio 4.1.3. It was solved when in the build script of the project, in the dependencies section of the buildscript, it was updated the version of the kotlin-gradle-plugin artifact from 1.4.10 to 1.4.32. Below is a copy paste from project build.gradle.kts:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3")
    }
}
```